# Relative layout messed up how fixed its position

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hello friends  i create relative layout which have text and media controller button when i start song it messed my layout please tell me how fixed its position here is code and pictures of my layout please help to fixed it i dont know fixed this how to fix relative layout position i am creating mp3 player which and i am facing this issue please help me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mediacontroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Song Name - [details]"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonBackward" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/song_title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Singer Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonBackward" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next_black_24dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_button_main"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonForward"
      android:src="@drawable/play_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonForward" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pausebtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/buttonForward"
        android:src="@drawable/pause_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonForward" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonBackward"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play_button_main"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_prev"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/pausebtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: when app launch it look fine]

[image: and when i play song the layout messed up kindly check now]

Comment: Hi, perhaps try wrapping the button controls in the bottom right using a  `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation? That will keep the buttons aligned with each other.

Comment: For `buttonBackward` there are 2 conflicting attributes (or at least inconsistent):`android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play_button_main"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/pausebtn"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to change visibility of play button to `android:visibility="invisible"` when this button is clicked or set play and pause buttons place based on other views position, no opposite (like now) when `buttonBackward` based on position of `play_button_main` and `pausebtn`.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a bit tricky the fact that you set one button as gone and the other as visible, especially given the constraint limitations and the fact that other buttons are also related with them.

The last line of buttonBackward seems to be the problem.
Instead of `gone`, use `invisible` for the play and pause buttons.

Ideally, if you insist on `gone`, then I would use a wrapper, (f.i. a FrameLayout) within which the two buttons would exist and all spatial constraints would have to do with the wrapper and not the buttons themselves.

Comment: Thank you answer also right but i  can accept only one answer